# OpenVPN handshake fail after Debian upgrade

Tags: debian, ssl, openvpn

I upgraded my Debian server from 7 to 9 few days ago and, since then, I can't connect to my openvpn anymore.

I tried to remove & purge openvpn and reinstall it with https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

But the handhshake still fail…

I also remove all the rules in iptables wihtout success.

I'm conecting with tunnleblick on MacOsxm here is the logs:

My config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote 92.*.21.* 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

the error:

```
2019-06-15 09:20:49.517373 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
2019-06-15 09:20:49.518603 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2019-06-15 09:20:49.519079 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
```

Comment: Is that error from the client or the server?  What do the openvpn logs look like on the server?

Comment: I don't have anything in my syslog… I got another server with the same version of OpenVPN (2.4) and my client connects to it without any trouble…

Comment: Sounds like the client is not even connecting to the server, which is not openvpn's fault.

Comment: @wurtel I don't get why i can't to this server from my client, I can still another openvpn server with the exact same config… Maybe the firewall?

Comment: Check with tcpdump on our outgoing interface to see if UDP packets to port 1194 are leaving your system. Something like: `tcpdump -ni eth0 port 1194`